# Como Iterar elementos y propiedades a traves de un plugin?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, charts

**Necesito que pueda imprimir las propiedades de cada uno**

*iterar los elementos con sus propiedades ya que los datos vienen de la base de datos*

> el datasets del plugin deberia hacer una iteración con sus elementos y
>   propiedades que serán asignada de la base de datos dinamicamente

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ctx = $("#bar-chartcanvas");
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost",
    type : "GET",
    success : function(data) {
        var len = data.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            console.log(data[i]);   
        var data_chart = {
            labels : [], 
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label :data[2][0],
                        data : [data[2][1]],
                        backgroundColor : [
                            "aqua",
                            "salmon",
                            "darkgray",
                            "pink",
                            "coral"
                        ]
                        borderWidth : 1
                    },
                ],
            }
        };
    }
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar debes crear un script php para traer los datos de tus tablas. Deben ser traídos en formato json.
 Este ejemplo te puede servir:

```
 <?php

 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
 $sqlQuery = "SELECT id,name,marks FROM marks ORDER BY id";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlQuery);
 $data = array();
   foreach ($result as $row) {
   $data[] = $row;
  }
  mysqli_close($conn);
  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

La solicitud AJAX, continuando con el ejemplo sería así:

```
function MostrarGrafico()
    {
        {
            $.post("data.php", // Aquí el script php
            function (data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                 var name = [];
                var marks = [];

                for (var i in data) {
                    name.push(data[i].name);
                    marks.push(data[i].marks);
                }

                var chartdata = {
                    labels: name,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'Calificaciones',
                            backgroundColor: '#49e2ff',
                            borderColor: '#46d5f1',
                            hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                            hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
                            data: marks
                        }
                    ]
                };

                var graphTarget = $("#divGraf");

                var barGraph = new Chart(graphTarget, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: chartdata
                });
            });
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Este ejemplo lo puedes adaptar fácilmente a lo que necesitas, espero que te sirva de guía.

Comment: para los elementos del plugin necesito que se iteren por cada dato que viene a traves de los datos de la base de datos ejemplo: si hay marks 2 el objeto 
datasets debe crear un nuevo objeto por cada item que se va a iterar